# Got confused on the term "expected covariance" when I read a paper.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I was reading a paper by Yi Ma: *Segmentation of Multivariate Mixed Data
via Lossy Data Coding and Compression*.

There is a line I don't understand, I've quoted here

> and the expected covariance is $\frac{1}{tr(\pi_j)} W \Pi_j W^T$.

I understand the trace of this matrix is the expected number of vectors from $w_1, w_2 ... w_m$ that are classified as class $j$. (because $\pi_{ij}$ is the probability of vector $w_i$ belongs to class $j$.

However, not sure why the expected covariance is $W \Pi_j W^T$, and what is exactly "expected covariance"?

You can download this paper via: [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~yima/coding/papers/Ma2007-PAMI.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eyima/coding/papers/Ma2007-PAMI.pdf)

Here is the snippet:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: It looks to me like it expands into $\sum_{i} (W_i-0)^2\pi_{ij}$ which looks like a variance rather than a covariance

Comment: @CalvinKhor yea, what i get is just $\pi_{ij}$ will be associated to each $w_i$ compared to the original form $WW^T$ (without $\Pi_j$), not sure why it is related to expectation.

Comment: i think by covariance, he means the element-wise, not vector-wise?